# How to get gitlab-runner to work with wildcards branch names

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

gitlab-runner 13.10

I want to kick off a job if the release branch starts with the project name 'release/projectname-310221'. I have a gitlab runner working perfectly when I push to a named branch using the only: method

```
only:
  - release/projectname-310321
```

if I use just 'release' or a regex 'release/project-.*$' it doesn't work

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rules` instead of `only` and check `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` :

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release\/project\-.*$/'
```